# Delete file after printing

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, printing

I'm trying to delete a file after printing it without success.

Practically, I need to print a PDF which is temporary generated (with text and image), then, when the printing process is done, I'd like to remove it.

Currently the PDF is being saved in Documents directory. Is it a good idea to save it in Temp folder? But then I'd have to remove it anyways.
I also have a tableView which shows the PDF the user **saved**, so I need to show only those (and not those **temporarily** generated)

I've tried with UIPrinterInteractionController's delegate methods, but without any luck.

```
-(void)printInteractionControllerDidDismissPrinterOptions:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController{
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",PDFNameString]];
    if ([fileMgr removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error] != YES)
    {   UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"UnableToDeleteFile", @"Unable to delete file: %@"),[error localizedDescription]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] autorelease];
        [alert show];
    }

    NSLog(@"Dismissed");
}
```

The alert view pops up just when the printing options view leaves place to "Sending to printer.." view.
It doesn't even delete the file, it says

Cocoa error code 4.

Does anyone know what method can I use to remove a file when the printing process is done?

**EDIT**

I NSLog'd if the file existed, and it doesn't. How is this possible?

Comment: Is the delegate method called at all? If so, what is the error you get when trying to delete the file?

Comment: Yes it is, in fact the alertView pops up! (and the NSLog with "Dismiss" shows up too). The error is (Cocoa error 4.)

Comment: I think this delegate method is supposed to be called after you dismiss the popup. So the question is - does the code you posted even get a chance to run?

Comment: Yes it does! Just soon after I select "Print" from the Printing options screen, the alertView is being shown, and the console says "Dismissed". But there is a view which says "Printing on [name of the printer]", then it's being dismissed

Comment: Not the error, but why not: `if (![fileMgr removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error])` instead of `if ([fileMgr removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error] != YES)`

Comment: James - yeah, you're right, I can write that way too!
Stavash - my bad, the delegate method was DidDismissPrinterOptions, not WillDismiss. Pasted the old code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try (void)printInteractionControllerDidFinishJob:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController instead.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate

Comment: Tried with this, worked. My error was that I missed a .pdf in [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",PDFNameString];

Thanks to everyone!